# object creation time from heap dump

Tags: java, heap-memory

Is there a way to figure out (even approximately) the creation time of an object from heap dump of a java process?

Please assume I don't have access to code and I have to work with the given dump. So I can't go and put timestamp in constructor.

Comment: By Creation, do you mean invoking constructor ?

Comment: constructor invocation time or after constructor finishes - it doesn't matter to me.

Comment: Rather than putting dummy text (which will annoy a lot of people), please describe your issue in more detail. Simply telling why you'd need that would have been enough.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe why you want to know this, because there may be a simpler way to do that.

Comment: I's a bit unclear if you need the creation time on ms / ns level or just "just after start", "after a while", "just before the bug is triggered" etc. What is the purpose of the timestamp?

Comment: An accuracy of an hour or so will do.

Comment: @Fakrudeen Did you resolve your issue finally using a custom agent?  Are you able to share your agent?  I'm running into a similar need, where I would love to track the creation times of objects in my Heap Dumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can find the timestamp from the given dump, but here are some suggestions if you can make new dumps.

If you only need very coarse time resolution such as (after startup, after 5 minutes, before manually triggering a bug, after manually triggering a bug etc), then you can take several dumps and compare them.

Otherwise, if you are able to add an agent and run the scenario again you can log this yourself. With your JDK in *$JAVA_HOME/demo/jvmti directory* there is a sample agent program *heapTracker* which can track object creation deletion. This could easily be modified to also include timestamp. See [Tools Interface](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tooldescr-136044.html#gbmls)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Store it in a long value, both before you start creating this object and call it again after the object is created.

Then, substract the two and you'll have the time it took.

NOTE: If you want to be more precise, you can also use `System.nanoTime()`, which I mostly use.

Comment: Thats an approximate solution but it does not relate to the question.

Comment: Why not? Did I misunderstand the question? I thought he wanted to have the creation time of an object, as in new ObjectClass();

Comment: He wants to know if he can determine Object creation time from a `heap dump of a java process`.

Comment: Agree with fyr - this is not what I want - please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TimerClass which is extended by all the classes in your application. You can place a timer attribute (which is an instance of java.util.Date) in the constructor of the TimerClass, which is initialized when the constructor is invoked. At any course of time whenever you want to know the time when the object was created, you can invoke the timer of that particular object. Since all the Classes in your application will be inheriting from this TimerClass, they will have access to timer attribute.

```
public class TimerClass{
    private Date timer;
    public TimerClass(){
        timer = new Date();
    }

    public getTimer(){
        return timer;
    }

}
```

Comment: i saw it after I had posted the comment. Let me give it a thought

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use "Java Heap Analysis Tool"
Have a look at it and find out whether it meets your requirement.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html

Comment: Yes - I am using jhat to analyze the heap dump. Just that I don't know if there is a way to find out object creation time.

Comment: At least for all the default reports that jhat provides, the creation timestamp is not there.